# Javascript onChange event equivalence for non-form-fields?

Tags: javascript

We know the onChange event only works for form fields. Is there any way to monitor the change of innerHTML of a specific DOM element other than form fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try using [DOMNodeInserted](http://javascript.gakaa.com/domnodeinserted-description.aspx) if that does the trick for you

update: another useful link: http://help.dottoro.com/ljmcxjla.php

Comment: I am actually looking for a way to monitor changes of innerHTML of a specific DOM node, not just DOM nodes insertion and removal.

Comment: take a look at this, unfortunately FF & webkit only: http://help.dottoro.com/ljrmcldi.php

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. Its supposed that you know when something in your own page changes:)
Can you give more details? maybe there is another way of doing what you need.

Comment: I am trying to "inject" javascript code (via bookmarklet) into a webpage that I have no control on. When the innerHTML of the DOM element with id="content_wrapper" is changed, another event will be fired.